# Acumatica Can't access Extension DAC from BLC

Tags: acumatica

Im trying to assign variables to my graph from InventoryItem and InventoryItemExt.

[image: Code]
[image]
(First Column is a InventoryItem Selector)
[image]

I've also tried using another PXSelectorAttribute, doing so I received an attribute error on runtime

`InventoryItemExt item2 = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<atcProjectLinesTable.itemNumber>(cache,line) as InventoryItemExt;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your FieldUpdated handler was declared for the atcProjectLinesTable DAC - cache parameter represents PXCache instance created for the atcProjectLinesTable DAC, not InventoryItem. I would assume the issue to happen when the system invokes `cache.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(item)`.

Try replacing the following line

```
InventoryItemExt item2 = cache.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(item);
```

with

```
InventoryItemExt item2 = item.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>();
```

Comment: It was working great, but now im receiving "Error #115: An error occurred while processing the field ItemNumber : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.." I didnt make any changes to the code and the error is resolved by commenting out the code. It's detecting the value in the item2 class? What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Probably your `item` variable equals null?

Comment: Thank you for replying! Thats what im confused about, "InventoryItemExt item2 = item.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>();" Is grabbing the extention data from InventoryItem, which Is still able to load the BasePrice variable. The code compiles and publishes so it's able to see the usrWattage variable in the InventoryItemExt scope.

Comment: This prevents the error,  
         
               ' if (item2 != null)
                {
                line.UnitWattage = item2.Usrwattage2;
                line.UnitLumens = item2.Usrlumens2;
                }' What would cause item2 to be null?

Comment: `item2` should never be equal to null

Comment: So if the code compiles and publishes could this be some DAC runtime issue? Ive tried cleaning the project but no luck

Comment: If the code compiles and publishes, nothing guaranties there will be no exceptions at runtime. Try first publishing your customization, then  restarting web server - probably something got messed up with runtime compilation.

Comment: Cleaning the project and restarting the web server did it, Thanks again!